# How to prove that extensions of Sobolev functions if Sobolev?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-derivatives

**Problem:**

Let us introduce this definition:

*Definition*: given an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and $u \in L_{loc}^1(\Omega)$ we say $v \in L_{loc}^1(\Omega)$ is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}u$ in the weak sense if for every $\varphi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$:

$$\int_{\Omega}u \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \varphi = \int_{\Omega} v \cdot \varphi$$

We can now formulate the question.

*Question*: Suppose that $u \in L_{loc}^1(\Omega^1)$ admits a weak derivative for every $i \in \{1, \dots, d\}$ and $w \in L_{loc}^1(\Omega^2)$ admits a weak derivative for every $i \in \{1, \dots, d\}$. Suppose $u=w$ in $\Omega^1 \cap \Omega^2$. If $\Omega := \Omega^1 \cup \Omega^2$, how can we prove that:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
u(x) \mbox{ if } x \in \Omega^1\\
w(x) \mbox{ if } x \in \Omega^2
\end{cases}$$
admits a weak derivative in $\Omega$?

**Attempt:**
I tried using approximation by $u \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ but I don't even know if we can.

Comment: I think that every $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2)$ can be split into some $\varphi_1 \in C_c^\infty(\Omega_1)$ and $\varphi_2 \in C_c^\infty(\Omega_2)$. This should help.

Comment: @gerw you are right, thank you very much!